# Error when you run a new spagobi application SBIErrorPage.title

Tags: spagobi

If you run the spagobi application on a Turkish operating system, you receive the following error

SBIErrorPage.title

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P33ej.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

If you run the spagobi application on a Turkish operating system, you receive the following error

{SpagoBI_Home}\bin open file catalina.bat

set JAVA_OPTS= add at the end of the line

-Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US

Result

set JAVA_OPTS= %JAVA_OPTS% -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US